# Suppose $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ satisfies $\int_G f(x)\,dx=\int_{\bar{G}}f(x)\,dx\ \ \text{for all open set } G\subset\mathbb R$, then $f=0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> **Problem:** Suppose $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ satisfies 
>   $$\int_G f(x) dx=\int_{\bar{G}}f(x) dx\ \ \text{for all open sets } G\subset\mathbb R.$$
>   Show that $f(x)=0$ for almost all $x\in\mathbb R$.

**My attempt:** For any open set $G\subset\mathbb R$, we can write $G=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (a_k,b_k)$, where $a_1<b_1\leq a_2<b_2\cdots$. The condition in the problem implies that $\int_{\cup_k\{a_k,b_k\}}f=0$, right? But it seems right for all $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ since $m(\cup_k\{a_k,b_k\})=0$. So I'm confused. What did I miss?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is strange... Isn't $$\int_G f = \int_{\overline{G}}f$$ true for all $L^1$ functions?

Comment: @Crostul No, it's not. This would imply that the boundary of any bounded open set has Lebesgue measure zero, which is false.

Comment: @Crostul take a fat Cantor set, then remove it from $[0,1]$. This is an open set, it has positive measure $<1$, and the closure has measure $1$.

Comment: I see. Thus the key for this problem is existence of fat Cantor sets. Well, we should recall this to the OP.

Comment: @cmk This is breaking my brain a bit here. Does that mean that the closure of $\cup_k (a_k, b_k)$ is not necessarily just $\cup_k [a_k, b_k]$?

Comment: Now that I think about it, it's obvious - the closure of $\cup_k (1/2^{k+1}, 1/2^k)$ contains $0$. The union of countably closed sets is not necessarily closed.

Comment: Thanks to all guys for the contribution in my problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well known fact: If $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ and $m(E_n)\to 0,$ then $\int_{E_n}f \to 0.$

Now suppose $f$ satisfies the given hypotheses. Let $I$ be any open interval. Then there exist open $G_1,G_2,\dots \subset I,$ with each $G_n$ dense in $I,$ such that $m(G_n)\to 0.$ By the above, $\int_{G_n}f \to 0.$ But for each $n,$

$$\int_{G_n}f = \int_{\overline{G_n}}f =\int_I f.$$

It follows that $\int_I f =0.$ Since this is true for any open interval $I,$ we have $\int_G f=0$ for any open $G.$ This gives $f=0$ a.e. as desired.

Comment: Can you explain why such $G_n$ exist?

Comment: @MarsPlastic  Let $E$ be the set of rationals in $I.$ Since $m(E) = 0$ there is an open set $U_n\supset E$ such that $m(U_n)<1/n.$ Define $G_n= U_n\cap I.$

Comment: @zhw. Understand now.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @zhw Ah, of course. Thank you for the nice explanation.

Comment: @MarsPlastic and Feng Shao, you're welcome.